# Exclude the word comment from being referenced

Tags: comments, seo

Lately i m trying improve my SEO, and i found in Google Webmaster Tools that the mains
 keywords are 'Comment' & 'Read more' it s a bit frustrating.
 How can I say to the search egine dont reference that words!

[Website](http://goo.gl/bCWNhB)

Thanks for help!

Comment: i still didnt try nothing yet I wanted get some advices first

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to add `rel="nofollow"` to comments. My theme maker gave me this hack that you can add in functions.php (no guarantee it will work for everyone, might depend on your theme):

```
function add_nofollow_to_comments_popup_link() {
    return ' rel="nofollow" ';
}
add_filter( 'comments_popup_link_attributes', 'add_nofollow_to_comments_popup_link' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If google is showing that, then you should consider getting a solid SEO plugin (or edit your theme) and do the following:

- Add proper meta titles
- Add proper meta keywords
- Add proper meta descriptions
- Make sure you have real content in your posts

Beyond that, you should check googles webmaster tools to see if you can exclude certain phrases. If the top words on your site are comment and read more, then you most likely just need to clean up your SEO ... but adding proper meta tags to your posts and pages.

Adding in a good sitemap wouldn't hurt either.

As long as you do the above, wordpress sites show up very well unless the theme creator didn't know what they are doing, which is not uncommon.

Looking at your site, most of your comments have the word comments in the link itself. Tweak the theme to add rel="nofollow" on those links. Do the same for all of the links labeled Read More on the site.

Since you already have the titles properly linked for your articles, that will tell search engines like google that the content of the target is that which it reads from the title, and not that which it reads from the comments and read more links.

That **should** help remedy the problem you are seeing, but you might want to read up a bit more on rel="nofollow" and how to use it properly in links.

Comment: i was using a solid SEO i Guess 'Yoast' but didnt prevent that kind of probléme i was thinking about some attribut to give to this link to dont index like nofollow for links to dont follow !

Comment: And between i m using a priemium them that look using well the metas u can check the link i added up

Comment: Updated after looking at your site. rel="nofollow" on the comment and read more links is probably the way to go.

Comment: Since wordpress included 'More' so i deleted theme's Read more. now just about comments. wich file should i Edit ? and add rel'nofollow'.

Comment: You will have to search your theme to figure out how it is displaying the comments links. This will likely be in one or more templates (index.php, etc.) but might also be in loop.php if your template uses that particular template. A quick directory scan of your theme for the word comments will probably be the fastest way to find it.

Comment: i Asked the theme creator and the Answer was : Hello. Are you reffering to the links inside the comments? The output is controlled by WordPress and not by the theme, you’ll need a plugin for that